# Why does Trunks not have Vegeta's hairstyle?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

[image]

Why does Trunks have his hair parted to the side, but Vegeta has a widow's peak? Shouldn't Trunks have some of the same features as Vegeta, just like Gohan inherited Goku's features?

Comment: We don't understand what you are trying to say especially what you mean by "side cut" or "widows peak".

Comment: @кяαzєя He's referring to their hairstyles, specifically their fringes, and asking why Trunks doesn't have the same hairstyle as his father. A quick Google search tells me that his *mother*, Bulma, has sported similar hairstyles to Trunks on occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas Gohan clearly inherited his looks from his father, Trunks appears to have inherited his looks from his *mother*, Bulma.

Here's a side-by-side comparison of Trunks and (a fanart of) Bulma as she appears in the Buu Saga. You can see they have very similar hairstyles - short bob cuts with centre-partings - and almost identical eyes:

[image]

Granted, their hair isn't exactly the same - and Bulma appears to change hairstyles a *lot* - but Gohan's hair is also slightly different to Goku's, if you look carefully at the spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Well seeing as though Trunks got his looks from Bulma he still got some of the same features. If you put Vegeta's hair on trunks they would look a lot similar.